# Why can't the Fourier partial sums of a continuous function tend to infinity at a point?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I know that there exists a $2\pi$ periodic continuous function whose Fourier series  diverges at a point.

However, I heard that for any $2\pi$ periodic continuous function $f(x)$, it is wrong that $\mid S_N(f,0)\mid \to \infty$ as $N$ goes to $\infty$.

Here $S_N(f,x)=1/2\pi\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}[\sin(N+1/2)(x-\theta)/\sin((x-\theta)/2)]f(\theta)d\theta$.

I tried with the $L^2$ convergence of $S_Nf$ to $f$. But this only shows that there exists 'some points' on which $S_Nf$ has a subsequence converging to $f$. Those points are not guaranteed to include $0$. So I am just stymied.

Comment: currently the formula for $S_n(f,x)$ seems to have nothing to do with $f$. I suggest using `\frac{a}{b}` for $\frac{a}{b}$? But in any case, if you know the first result, then you can simply translate the point of divergence to 0, right? Or just follow the proof here http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/fun/notes_2012-13/05b_banach_fourier.pdf

Comment: Oops I will edit it. A typo

Comment: What do you mean by translate the point of divergence? Do I define another function $g(x)=f(x-a)$ if $a$ is the point of divergence for $f$? Then $g$ is a different function from $f$.

Comment: And the link does not say anything about the convergence of the whole series of partial sums....

Comment: Oh, I see the distinction. You know that its divergent, but you want to know if it specifically diverges to plus/minus infinity. OK, sorry

Comment: Not that it says anything about $x=0$, but you seem to be unaware of Carleson's theorem: If $f\in L^2$ then $S_Nf\to f$ almost everywhere.

Comment: I mentioned the fact in my question and that it does not seem to help much.

Comment: You cannot really know on which points the partial sums converge.

Comment: No, it doesn't help much, but no you didn't mention that fact! You alluded to the fact that some subsequence converges to $f$ almost everywhere. That's completely trivial - Carleson's theorem is not trivial, it's like the deepest theorem in the theory of Fourier series.

Comment: Oh I see... there is a huge difference.... however that deep theorem does not seem to help either....

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer in general. But if $f$ is real-valued it's very simple.

> > **Easy Lemma.** Suppose $(x_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers such that $|x_n|\to\infty$ and $|x_{n+1}-x_n|$ is bounded. Then $\left|\frac{x_1+\dots+x_n}n\right|\to\infty$.

(Hint: The hypothesis implies that either $x_n\to+\infty$ or $x_n\to-\infty$.)

Now set $$\sigma_n(f)=\frac{s_1(f)+\dots+s_n(f)}n$$as usual. If $f$ is a real-valued continuous function and $|s_n(f,0)|\to\infty$ then $|\sigma_n(f,0)|\to\infty$, which is impossible since $\sigma_n(f)=f*K_n\to f$ uniformly. (Where of course $K_n$ is the Fejer kernel.)

But the lemma is false for sequences of complex numbers...

(Say $C_j$ is the circle of radius  $j$ centered at the origin. Let $(z_n)$ be a sequence consisting of one point on $C_1$, then two points evenly spaced on $C_2$, then three on $C_3$, etc. Then $(z_1+\dots+z_n)/n\to0$.)

Comment: Why is the lemma false for complex numbers?

Comment: @Keith Why it's false really doesn't matter, unless you think you can prove it's true. I added a description of what I believe is a counterexample in an edit just now.